# Logical equivalence without truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove:
$(r\leftrightarrow\neg\ p) \wedge p \equiv \neg\ r \wedge p$

I didn't suceed without truth table.

Comment: Are you supposed to argue informally or with deduction rules?

Comment: I can use only the rules of replacement.

Comment: Replace $r\leftrightarrow \neg p$ with $(r\to \neg p)\land (\neg p\to r)$, then use $\phi\to \psi\equiv \neg \phi \lor \psi$ on both implications, distribute everything, etc.

Comment: I tryed that way but it lead me nowhere...

Comment: This is why it's not a bad idea to show your work. Do it and someone will surely be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replace $(r\leftrightarrow\neg\ p)$ by the disjunction $(r \wedge \lnot p) \lor (\lnot r \wedge p).$ Then distribute the $p$ over these two terms. The first one, $(r \wedge \lnot p) \land p,$ is contradictory and so may be dropped, while the remaining one is $(\lnot r \land p) \land p,$ equivalent to $\lnot r \land p.$

Comment: Can you please explain the disjunction?

Comment: The double arrow is same as $(r \rightarrow \lnot p ) \land (\lnot p \rightarrow r)$ This is in turn the same as $(\lnot r \lor  \lnot p) \land ( p \lor r).$ If the and is now distributed over the two ors, two of the four resulting conjunctions are false and the other two are as noted above after the phrase "the disjunction".

Answer (score 0):

The right side proposition is true only when $r$ is false and $p$ is true. The left side proposition is also true only when $p$ is true and $r$ is false. Hence they are equivalent.

Comment: I know, but I want to get to the left side from the right side.